# I have a fully functioning program that I need to split up into 3 methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I am fine with java code and programming as long as it's just using the main method. But using multiple methods is just confusing for me. But for it to be more professional it needs to obviously be split up so it can be changed easier. I've been searching for hours for an example of a program similar to mine but I could not find one and now I'm just stuck.

The fully functioning program

```
package test5555;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test5555 {

    private static int[] randomInteger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean validInput = false;
        randomInteger = new int[101];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger.length; i++)
            randomInteger[i] = rand.nextInt();
        int indexPosition = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the array index position: ");

            String s = null;
            while (!validInput) {
                try {
                    if (s != null) {
                        indexPosition = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    } else {
                        indexPosition = input.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]);
                    validInput = true;
                } catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");
                    input.nextLine();
                    s = input.next();
                    if (s.equals("quit")) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to do the following:

- Calls a method that creates an Array with 100 Random Generated Integers
- Calls a method that prompts the user to enter an index position of the array and returns the value entered.  If the value entered by the user is not a valid integer, throw an" Input Mismatch Exception" that prompts the user of the problem and permits them the opportunity to input a correct integer or exitprogram
- Calls a method  that receives the value that the user entered as an index position in the array. The method  will display the corresponding value in the index position of the value entered. If the value entered by the user is outside of a valid index position in the array, throw an" Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception".
- All exception should be detected in their associated methods and handled in the main method

What I have attempted and changed and failed many times so far

```
package exceptionhandling;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class ExceptionHandling {
    private static int[] randomInteger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Need to call the three methods
        //Need to handle all exceptions

    }

    public static void createArray() //Method to create the array filling with 100 random integers
        {

            randomInteger = new int[101];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger.length; i++)
                randomInteger[i] = rand.nextInt();

        }

    public static void enterIndex(int[] numbers) //Is this calling the array correctly? Method to prompt the user to enter indexPosition
        {
            //should I just put my 'try else catch' loop in here along with the input InputMismatchException and have that take the value of the indexPosition variable which I will call in the main method?

        }

    public static void getarrayValue(int[] numbers) //Definitely not formatted properly. Method to get the value from the array based on the indexPosition from user

    // Don't think this method should be void, it should return the value from the array associated with the indexPosition. Do I do the same loop as above but this time with the IndexOutOfBoundsException and then return System.out.println(randomInteger[indexPosition]); (or without the system.out.printnln

}
```

edit for @Debosmit Ray because I couldn't fit it into a comment. Okay so thank very much for the help it really helped in showing me how I should break up my methods. I just have two questions / problems. I added `break;` after `System.out.println("Value at index: " + num[indx] );` so there won't be an infinite loop. And I added `System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");` after the `} catch and the exceptions`. How do I make it so that when I run it and type 'bob' it only says my `System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");` statement instead of mine and the original loop statement `"Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: "`. And number 2, I cannot get the the `IndexOutOfBound exception` to work, it just crashes

Comment: If I may, `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); {` why have you opened braces after initializing a Scanner object?

Comment: Its great that you want to split up the chunk into smaller blocks, but at least get the initial block working first.

Comment: This is homework and so you must show us a decent attempt, meaning those empty methods should have code in them, else how can we guess what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: @DebosmitRay correct I had an extra opened brace there and a closed brace at the end.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is homework but I created the original program so I'm not just asking for all the work. I included // notes to ask if that's what I should be doing like if I'm on the right track

Comment: The key to programming is to experiment to try. Rather than ask, try it out and see if it works. What have you got to lose in the attempt?

Comment: Well. That's not how a `Scanner` works. Please visit [this link](http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html) and fix your initial code block. Once that is working, you can let us know if you are facing problems.

Comment: @DebosmitRay What do you mean..? My program with just using the main method works perfectly and uses scanner

Comment: @DebosmitRay: The extra unneeded braces provide a distraction, but shouldn't adversely affect the functioning of his main method. They certainly don't affect how his Scanner is working, and could just as easily have been moved to the next line.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's fine now. Yay!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I removed the closing brace as well. Just at a previous edit cause I removed the wrong { at first

Comment: @DebosmitRay Okay so can you tell me if the //notes I have in my methods are on the right track and if I initialized the array correctly

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels are you just trolling me I don't understand. Please copy my code and run it and show me how it is non-functional because I have made sure that it runs perfectly lol...

Comment: @archer I'll add a brief answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a brief intro to how you can go about breaking your code up into parts. Let me know if there are any questions. I haven't written out everything that you mentioned and I feel that you will be able to get that stuff down yourself. Please read through the code before running it. Let me know if you need any help. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloArcher {

    private static int[] randomInteger;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = getRandArray(100);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
        while(true) {
            int indx = getUserIndex(s);
            System.out.println("Index:" + indx);

            if(indx < 0 || indx > num.length) {
                // throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Wrong index bro");
                continue;
            }    
            System.out.println("Value at index: " + num[indx] );
        }
    }

    public static int[] getRandArray(int n) {
        int[] randomInteger = new int[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < randomInteger.length; i++)
            randomInteger[i] = rand.nextInt();

        return randomInteger;
    }

    public static int getUserIndex(Scanner s) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: ");
        String in = s.next();
        if(in.equals("quit")) 
            System.exit(0);

        int indx = -1;

        try { 
            indx = Integer.parseInt(in);
        } catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException | IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            // weird value entered - run function again; quit is the only way to exit
            indx = getUserIndex(s);
        }
        return indx;
    }
}
```

Some sample output

> sh-4.3$ javac HelloArcher.java
>   sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloArcher
>   Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:
>   5
>   Index:5
>   Value at index: -472718090
>   Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:
>
> -1                                                                                                                                                                            Index:-1
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Wrong index bro
>
> ```
>     at HelloArcher.main(HelloArcher.java:17)
> ```

Testing you 'bob' input

> sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloArcher
>   Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:
>   bob
>   Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:
>   1
>   Index:1
>   Value at index: 1138796751
>   Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit:
>   quit

Comment: Hi so thank you very much and I am so close to being finished. I made an edit at the bottom of my original post specifically about this and if you could help me out that would be much appreciated

Comment: @archer The infinite-ness of the loop was to show that typing `quit` was the only way to exit the program. Putting a `break` after the `System.out.println("Value at index: " + num[indx] );` is fine if you want to let the user enter valid index only once.

Comment: @archer If there is any error in getting an integer value from the user input, the catch block ensures that the function is called again. So, no need to add anything else. I will make the prompt change in my answer.

Comment: @archer About the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. In `main()`, after checking to see if `n` is between 0 and 100, you can replace the IllegalArgumentException with ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Please see edited code.

Comment: I think making any more changes to this Q/A is outside the scope of this question

Comment: @archer It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is still not working correctly. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 100 or type quit to exit: 
 at helloarcher.HelloArcher.main(HelloArcher.java:24)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: @archer added output

Comment: Isn't ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException supposed to be for numbers that you cannot enter. I've been talking about if you enter something < 0 or > 100 such as -5 or 102 it doesn't catch it, the program crashes

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. You've been a humongous help